# How to use format-specific options in ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick

Currently I'm trying to convert to HEIF, but the only HEIF-related option is heic:preserve-orientation (in CLI option [define](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#define)). How can I use other format-specific settings like quality, lossless mode,... for HEIF and other formats? Thanks!

Edit:
For my case, I use `-define heif:quality=x` which gives no difference whatever `x` is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check HEIC/HEIF support in your installed version of **ImageMagick** with:

```
magick identify -list format | grep -Ei "HEIC|HEIF|Mode"
```

---

The only `define` in ImageMagick that I can find is the one you mention. I search by going into the git repository and running:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -Ei "heic:|heif:" {} +
```

which gives:

```
./coders/heic.c:  option=GetImageOption(image_info,"heic:preserve-orientation");
./www/command-line-options.html:    <td>heic:preserve-orientation</td>
```

---

If you want to try different compression options, you can check what is available in your installation with:

```
magick identify -list compress
```

**Output**

```
B44A
B44
BZip
...
Fax
Group4
...
JPEG
LosslessJPEG
Lossless
LZMA
LZW
None
...
Zstd
```

Then you can choose one you want to use from that list and use it like this:

```
magick input.png -compress lossless result.heic
```

---

You can use the regular (normal) `-quality` setting too, like this:

```
magick input.jpg -quality 80 result.heic
```

I understand, from your own comments and experiments, that `-quality -1` results in lossless compression.

Comment: Mine (macOS 10.14 with latest version from Homebrew) gives `HEIC: rw-`. I don't know what `rw-` means, there're `rw+` as well. However I can really compress it.

Comment: Ok, your installation is more up-to-date than mine. I guess you would use the normal `compression` settings then so, run `identify -list compress` to find what is possible and then use `-compress LZW` or `-compress Lossless` or whatever you like from the list.

Comment: For quality, just use `-quality 80` or whatever you like.

Comment: Whoa it works! I did read the `-quality` option, but they said that it's only for PNG/JPEG, so I didn't try. Thanks! Seems `-1` gives lossless.

Comment: Your `-quality` options gives me the intended results. Please include this in the answer so I can mark it accepted!